# How to pass data to server using HttpClient in xamarin.android

Tags: c#, post, xamarin.android, dotnet-httpclient

I am developing one android app in xamarin,now i want  to make post request and send following data to server

```
Name 
EmailID
Prod_EMAILID
ID
```

and get the responce from server [Link of API](http://52.163.215.46:4444/api/FBLogins).I have done something like this

```
static async Task CallWebAPIAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:55587/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));                

        //POST Method
        var post = new Post() { Id = 1,NAME="aaaaa222",PROF_EMAILD="aaa@gmail.com",MAILID="asasa@gmail.com" };
        HttpResponseMessage responsePost = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Department", post);
        if (responsePost.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Get the URI of the created resource.
            Uri returnUrl = responsePost.Headers.Location;
            Console.WriteLine(returnUrl);
        }        
    }
    Console.Read();    
}
```

But it works only for GET method now i want to make post request and in Httpclient

Comment: I would recommend looking into http://restsharp.org/ it can connect to your API and parse the JSON result into C# objects

Comment: I want to use HttpClient.How to implement it

Comment: What is the error you are having?

Comment: HttpClient doesnot contain defination for PostAsJsonAsync

Comment: Now i get the error like The name Encoading doesnot exists in current context

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I use HttpClient in my solution

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myPoco));
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://your-url"), content);

    /* handle response here*/
};
```

Where myPoco is your plain C# objet